# Приглашаю в канал Телеграм или на канал?

Tags: грамматика

Создала в Телеграме канал. Разместила в группе ссылку с приглашением в канал. Получила в ответ замечание, что надо писать "на канал". Когда речь о ТВ, говорю, конечно, на канале. А вот в этом случае как? В самом Телеграмме употребляется предлог "в".

Comment: *Телеграм* лучше написать с маленькой буквы

Answer (score 1):

В некоторых случаях "канал" является родственником "чату", где человек  принимает активное участие, является вовлеченным в его жизненный процесс, оставляет часть своих мыслей внутри.
Но есть чисто информационные каналы, где пользователь не имеет возможности что либо обсуждать.
На мой взгляд, следует разделять эти понятия: в первом случае применять предлог "в", во втором - "на".

Answer (score 0):

В повседневной речи чаще говорят "в Телеграм-канал".
Предполагаю, что эта относительно устоявшаяся речевая норма станет стандартной.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда говорю "на канал", "на телеграм-канале". Эта форма кажется благозвучнее и естественнее, чем "в канале".
Поэтому правильно вас поправили. Ссылка с приглашением "на канал".
"Переходите на мой канал". Всегда слово "канал", если имелся в виду способ передачи информации, употреблялось с предлогом "на". "Передача, рубрика на нашем канале".